# Xcode, can Bundle Display Name be a variable for Product Name

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I see that $(PRODUCT_NAME) can be a variable for Bundle display name within the plist file,

but I would like the opposite to occur, for $(BUNDLE_NAME) to be the variable within Product Name in the target info. Is that a real variable? Can I make it one? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your target, go to "Build Settings" and add a "User-Defined Setting" (e.g. DISPLAY_NAME).

Then, go to the `Info.plist` of your target and add "Bundle display name" key and set its value to "$(DISPLAY_NAME)"